# How would you translate "S'emmêler les pinceaux" in english?

Tags: phrase-requests, french

It is a french phrase which could be translate as "Tangling the brushes" which means being confuse.

Is there a phrase to say that you are confused in english?

Comment: ***confuse the issue***, or more colloquially, [***muddy the waters***,](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/muddy-the-waters) which might lead the confused person to say ***It's as clear as mud to me***.

Comment: 'I am confused' is not the same as 'You're confusing me'; I assume the French expression is the active version, with the speaker doing the tangling / confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Getting your wires crossed** is often used when 2 parties miscommunicate and end up with differing ideas as to what the situation is, often with hilarious and/or unfortunate circumstances.